# "How can I exceed the maximum number of connections in PostgreSQL and Spark JDBC

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, connection

I have a PostgreSQL database with at least 2 tables.

I want to test a scenario where I exceed the maximum number of connections. However, for some reason, I am unable to achieve the desired results, and all my runs are successful. I am trying to understand why.

When I check the number of connections in my database by running `'show max_connections'`, I get a result of `100`.

Now, I am attempting to run Spark JDBC with, for example, 200 connections by setting 'numOfPartitions' to 200. I am expecting to receive an exception.

```
val df = ScalaSession.reader.read
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test")
.option("user", "test")
.option("dbtable", s"${param}")
.option("password", "test")
.option("fetchsize", "1000")
.option("partitionColumn", "id")
.option("lowerBound", "0")
.option("upperBound", "1000")
.option("numPartitions", "200")
.option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
.load()

df.count()
```

Scenario 2:

I am attempting to run the above code in parallel by creating 2 threads, with each thread executing the count query on different tables. My intention is to run the first query and utilize all the connections, and then execute the second thread to access the database. I am expecting to encounter a 'Connections limit exceeded' exception, but to my surprise, nothing happens. In the Spark UI, I can still observe that both jobs are running in parallel

```
class MyThread(param: String) extends Runnable {

  override def run() {
    val df = ScalaSession.reader.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test")
      .option("user", "test")
      .option("dbtable", s"${param}")
      .option("password", "test")
      .option("fetchsize", "1000")
      .option("partitionColumn", "id")
      .option("lowerBound", "0")
      .option("upperBound", "1000")
      .option("numPartitions", "200")
      .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
      .load()

    df.count()
  }

}

class MyThread2(param: String) extends Runnable {

  override def run() {
    val df = ScalaSession.reader.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test")
      .option("user", "test")
      .option("dbtable", s"${param}")
      .option("password", "test")
      .option("fetchsize", "1000")
      .option("partitionColumn", "id")
      .option("lowerBound", "0")
      .option("upperBound", "1000")
      .option("numPartitions", "200")
      .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
      .load()

    df.count()

  }
}

// Creating object
object MainObject {
  // Main method
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val th1 = new Thread(new MyThread("atable"))
    th1.setName("1")
    th1.start()

    print("Go to sleep")
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    print("I am woke up")

    val th2 = new Thread(new MyThread2("btable"))
    th2.setName("2")
    th2.start()
  }
}

object ScalaSession {
  val reader = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[2]")
    .appName("spark test")
    .config("spark.sql.legacy.sizeOfNull", false)
    .getOrCreate()
}
```

How can I reproduce the 'connection exceeded' exception?"

Answer (score 0):

the connection is short-lived and it'll close itself once the spark executor finish requesting the database.

Try to add a more complicated process in order to increase the connection time to live.